# AngularJS functions in the factory cannot be accessed from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im new to angular js.
Can anyone please tel me why i get an error saying functions in the factory cannot be accessed from the controller.

> Error: UserService.getAllCustomers is not a function

This happens when I add

```
  App.service('UserService', function () { })
```

to the controller.
If this is not added it gives

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown
>   provider:serServiceProvider<-UserService<- UserController

Comment: D you have a more complet code ?

Comment: This issues seems like UserService does not have getAllCustomers  function

Answer (score 0):

You should have someting like :

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('serviceName',[
        function () {
            return function () {
                /*your code */
            };
         }]);


angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('controllerName',['serviceName'
        function (serviceName) {

         }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The userService does not have the "getAllCustomers"

```
  var App= angular.module('myApp', []);

    App.controller("MyCtrl", ['UserService', function(UserService) {
      UserService.getAllCustomers();
    }]);

    App.service('UserService', function() {
      this.getAllCustomers = function() {
        alert('getAllCustomers');
      }
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8139/)

Note: If you removed "UserService" from the app ,so the UserService is not available in the app, but you are injected in controller then angular will check UserService is created or not, if it is not created it will throw the error like Error:

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:serServiceProvider<-UserService<-
>   UserController

Comment: After adding app.service it gives
UserService.getAllCustomers(); is not a function.
Any idea about this.